# Point www.domain.org to a specific Github project page?

Tags: github-pages

I would like to point www.deeplearningbook.org directly to the Github project page goodfeli.github.io/book.

However, this github help page ( https://help.github.com/articles/about-custom-domains-for-github-pages-sites/#subdomains ) makes it sound like I could only have book.deeplearningbook.org or goodfeli.deeplearningbook.org/book point to goodfeli.github.io/book. Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

> You can configure a custom domain for User, Organization, and Project Pages.

An, yes the Github documentation is sometimes confusing.

In your case, you will point both `deeplearningbook.org` and `www.deeplearningbook.org` to `goodfeli.github.io/book`.

Go to your DNS provider and :

1. create two A records for your apex domain `deeplearningbook.org` pointing to `192.30.252.153` and `192.30.252.154` ([documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/tips-for-configuring-an-a-record-with-your-dns-provider/))
2. create a CNAME record for `www.deeplearningbook.org` pointing to `goodfeli.github.io` ([documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/tips-for-configuring-a-cname-record-with-your-dns-provider/))

Go to your `goodfeli.github.io/book` Github repository an create a CNAME file at the root, containing `deeplearningbook.org`.

You then have to be patient. DNS replication can take up to 48 hours. Usually in one or two hours, you can reach your newly set domain.

Answer (score 0):

I was eventually about to do this by adding A links to github.io rather than just the CNAME link. The full instructions are here: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9645/2208/how-do-i-link-my-domain-to-github-pages